# Issue fetching all rows from postgres database n python

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, discord.py

Hi I'm having an issue fetching all rows from my table and printing them all in one rather that fetching a row and returning the data one by one. Is there a way you can get all rows in one.

Here is what I'm working with:

```
async def r_list(self, ctx):
    """Gets a list of restricted users."""
    
    guild = ctx.message.guild
    for member in guild.members:
        conn = psycopg2.connect(DATABASE_URL, sslmode='require')
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute("SELECT time, username FROM blacklist WHERE username=%s AND time IS NOT NULL", (member.id, ))
        results = cursor.fetchall()
        for row in results:
            user_id=row[1]
            username = self.bot.get_user(user_id)
            timestamp=row[0].strftime("%#d %b %Y, at %I:%M%p")
            await ctx.send(f"User: {username} Until: {timestamp}")
        
    cursor.close()
    conn.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `WHERE` clause will filter out most of the other rows, so in case you really want *all* rows, you can use

```
SELECT * FROM blacklist
```

This will return every column from every row, rather than only the rows where the id's match. Afterwards, `fetchall()` should do the trick.

Comment: Would this print all the rows out one by one? I would like to get all the rows then print in one list.

Comment: No, this gives you a list of all rows, like you wanted.

Comment: Thanks, it still seems to be printing rows one by one in the console. I must be looking at this wrong.

Comment: Your code doesn't have a `print` anywhere, can you update the post to show where you put it? That might help identify the issue.